# How to modify chapter number size in memoir using veelo

Tags: chapters, memoir, size

I'm using the `\documentclass{memoir}` and `\chapterstyle{veelo}` in my LaTeX document. However, I want to customize the size of the chapter numbers displayed in the document. By default, the chapter numbers are quite large, and I would like to make them smaller to better match the overall design of my document.

I have tried searching for solutions online, but I couldn't find any specific instructions for modifying the chapter number size when using the veelo chapter style. The solutions I found were mostly related to other chapter styles or customizations using other document classes.

Could someone please guide me on how to change the size of the chapter numbers when using `\chapterstyle{veelo}` and `\documentclass{memoir}`? Specifically, I would like to reduce the font size of the chapter numbers to better suit my document's layout.

I want to decrease the size of, in this case, the number 1.

[image: chapter1]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The chapter nuumber is sized using `\resizebox` from the `graphicx` package, so in order to change its size you need to adjust the size of the box its printed in.  Here's an example of how to do that; you may also want to change the size of the black rectangle as well.

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\chapterstyle{veelo}
   \renewcommand*{\printchapternum}{%
     \makebox[0pt][l]{%
       \hspace{.8em}%
       \resizebox{!}{.4\beforechapskip}% adjust .4 as desired
       {\chapnumfont \thechapter}%
       \hspace{.8em}%
       \rule{.5\midchapskip}{\beforechapskip}% adjust .5 as desired
     }%
   }
\usepackage{kantlipsum}
\begin{document}
\chapter{A chapter}
\kant
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]